# How do I remove my credit card from Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

I want to remove my credit card from Google Play because a random money glitch in a game is worrying me.

Google Wallet isn't compatible with my phone.

Comment: this is the first link https://support.google.com/wallet/answer/2907561?hl=en on google with (remove+credit+card+google+wallet)

Answer (score 7):

Please follow the following steps

1. Login to [Google Wallet](https://wallet.google.com/manage/)
2. Click on `Payment Methods`
3. On the card which you want to remove, click `Remove`
4. Confirm the prompt for card removal

This should remove the Credit card from Google play store.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work unless you have or replace the payment method with another, but if you wish to remove all payment methods - you cannot do it this way or anyway probably.